# Print the key for the maximum out of data set

Tags: python

Currently my data set is:

```
{('NSW', '06'): 0.4, ('QLD', '06'): 0.2, ('VIC', '06'): 0.0, ('NSW', '07'): 0.2, ('QLD', '07'): 0.4, ('VIC', '07'): 0.0, ('NSW', '08'): 0.2, ('QLD', '08'): 0.2, ('VIC', '08'): 0.0, ('NSW', '09'): 0.2, ('QLD', '09'): 0.2, ('VIC', '09'): 0.0, ('NSW', '10'): 0.2, ('QLD', '10'): 0.2, ('VIC', '10'): 0.0, ('NSW', '11'): 0.2, ('QLD', '11'): 0.6, ('VIC', '11'): 0.0}
```

I have achieved this from doing:

```
key = (state,month)
    if key not in rainfall_and_month:
        rainfall_and_month[key] = rainfall
    if key in rainfall_and_month:
        rainfall_and_month[key] = min(rainfall, rainfall_and_month[key])
```

I wish to print out the largest value out of the key-value pairs. So basically I would like to make the code find "('QLD', '11'): 0.6", and then print out,

```
A-value: QLD
B-value: 11
```

separately, so I would probably end up doing

```
print("A-value:", state)
print("B-value:", month)
```

However I'm not sure as to how to find the largest value then extract those data points.

Comment: You gotta at least make an attempt and put it up here.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, dictionaries have a method called `.items()` which returns a generator of the dictionary items as a tuple of tuples. Python 2 equivalent is `.iteritems()`. In your case, if the dict is named `data_dict`

```
dict_items = data_dict.items()
```

The `max` function in Python allows you to enter a lambda function, which basically tells it what value to compare by.

```
max_item_tuple = max(dict_items, key=lambda currentTuple: currentTuple[1])
```

Now your `max_item_tuple` contains the tuple of the key value pair that you need from your dict.

For example, if I had a dictionary of `{"something": 1, "nothing": 4, "everything": 3}`, my `max_item_tuple` would become `("nothing", 4)`.

Comment: why the Tuple? sorry

Comment: Once I converted the dictionary into items, the key value pairs became key value tuples instead. Check the edited answer. something like `{1: "a"}` will become `[(1, 'a')]`.

Answer (score 0):

here is an alternative to `lambda`:

```
>>> max_pair = max(data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
('QLD', '11')
>>> max_pair[0]
'QLD'
>>> max_pair[1]
'11'
```

Comment: What is this system of normal brackets called? Since I know square brackets are for lists, curly brackets are for dictionaries, so what are () brackets for?

Comment: it's for `tuple`.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use `max` to find max of value. It takes a keyword parameter `key` which can be assigned to value based on what you need to find the maximum of.

Consider using [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/operator.html) module. `operator.itemgetter(1)` takes the value of each key in every iterations.

```
import operator

s = {('NSW', '06'): 0.4, ('QLD', '06'): 0.2, ('VIC', '06'): 0.0, ('NSW', '07'): 0.2, ('QLD', '07'): 0.4, ('VIC', '07'): 0.0, ('NSW', '08'): 0.2, ('QLD', '08'): 0.2, ('VIC', '08'): 0.0, ('NSW', '09'): 0.2, ('QLD', '09'): 0.2, ('VIC', '09'): 0.0, ('NSW', '10'): 0.2, ('QLD', '10'): 0.2, ('VIC', '10'): 0.0, ('NSW', '11'): 0.2, ('QLD', '11'): 0.6, ('VIC', '11'): 0.0}

result = max(s.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

A_value = result[0][0]  # QLD
B_value = result[0][1]  # 11
```